# Is there a pentium equivalent of any i-series processor?

Tags: performance, cpu-architecture, intel-core-i3

I have a confusion with speed of processors and I want to know what makes say, i3 faster than pentium processor which pentium doesn't have? If we add more GHz to pentium will it be same as i3 in some cases?

I have read about Turbo boost technology and Hyper-threading. Is that all which makes the difference to how many Instructions per second can be processed?

Comment: You can look up the differences at [ark.intel.com](http://ark.intel.com) - search for the processor and once you have the one of interest select `Compare +`.  Then when you have at least two you can select `Compare Specifications` at the top of the pages. i,e, [3GHz i3 vs G3220](http://ark.intel.com/compare/77773,77487)

Comment: Recommended reading: http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/

Comment: [Megahertz Myth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megahertz_myth).

Comment: So, I guess another important factor is pipeline? But the number is also decreased from 30 to just around 14 for icore processors.

Comment: There are many factors that affect CPU's performance. Clock frequency, number of physical cores, number of logical cores, cache size, count of instructions per cycle, instruction set (including availability of SIMD extensions) just to name some. What's more, CPUs can perform better at some tasks and worse at others. There's no Ultimate CPU Performance Factor. The most reliable measure of performance are results of benchmarks that simulate the task you're going to perform on that CPU.

Comment: Intel has not made a pentium processor for several generations except for the anv edition